# Using google guava error - Not under a public suffix: display_url

Tags: eclipse, scala, guava

I'm trying to use the `InternetDomainName` function from google Guava; I've written the code in scala using Eclipse and it compiles fine, but when I run it, I keep getting an error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not under a public suffix: display_url
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
at com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName.topPrivateDomain(InternetDomainName.java:445)
```

I've already added `"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "16.0"` to the dependency library, and added the Guava library to the project. I'm not sure what it is implying. Is it because I've entered data that are not URL?

Answer (score 3):

As always, the answer is in the documentation. Let's see the [`topPrivateDomain()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html#topPrivateDomain()) method:

> Throws:
>
> - `IllegalStateException` - if this domain does not end with a public suffix

And, actually, "display_url" does not indeed end with a public suffix. So the method has nothing to return and throws as defined. Try some actually useful URL instead.